# Reading the baptismal entry for Wolff Schweitzer's child (Sontra 1636)

Tags: palaeography, church-records, kurrent, german

I'm having a bit of trouble reading and translating the "Mar" section at the bottom here:

[image]

At the moment, I have:

```
Wolff Schweitzers kind hain Schwager gewaffen
Hans Schmüch Mayer kind Margarata Claüs Brüek 
    frau gehatten
```

I'm not even sure if that's one entry, or two, as I can't figure out the meaning of the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is:

```
Mar: Wolff Schweitzers Kindt sein Schwager gevatter
```

Translated:

```
March: Wolff Schweitzers child his brother-in-law godparent
```

The author had a certain vertical drift, so the next line starting with "Hans" is indeed a different entry.

Keep in mind that the meaning of "schwager" depends on era and local customs, but it seems to be unambiguous to the author.

Comment: Thanks. He definitely didn't mince words, unfortunately...